# Create dynamic table from knockout view model with fixed first column

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want to create dynamic table based on days in month and apply knockout bindings on it.
So far I've created basic table and generated *tds*.

This is my KO view model:

```
 var WorkerModel = function (_workerId, _workerFullName, _daysOfTask) {
     this.workerId = _workerId;
     this.workerFullName = _workerFullName;
     this.daysOfTask = _daysOfTask;
 };

 var AppViewModel = {

     daysInMonth: ko.observable(),
     workersArray: ko.observableArray(),

     getWorkers: function () {
       // get workers from server
     }
 }
```

I've created jsfiddle example:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/freshbm/Hy3mz/)

Problem is, I don't know how to determine if dayOfMonth is dayOfTask and add html to that .

> foreach: daysInMonth - create td
>
> if (daysOfTask[i] == dayOfMonth) put html: "W" in td

Also how can I iterate with *ko.observable()*? In fiddle I've put daysInMonth as *observableArray()* but duno how to create `for loop` with knockout. Something like this:

> daysInMonth = ko.observable(15);
>
> < ko for (i=0; i < daysInMont; i++) >
>
> ... some code
>
> < /ko >

Basicly I want to get this table layout:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.

You can use the `if` binding to conditionally display the "W"s. You just need to use the [`indexOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (or if your browser is not supporting it then use of the implementation which are exist in jQuery, underscore.js, etc.) to check whether the current item in the `daysInMonth` collection is inside in the `daysOfTask` array.

You can get the current item from the `daysInMonth` with the `$data` property and the actual  `daysOfTask` array with the `$parent` [contextual binding properties](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

```
<!-- ko foreach: $root.daysInMonth-->
    <td>
        <!-- ko if: $parent.daysOfTask.indexOf($data) != -1 -->
            W
        <!-- /ko -->
    </td>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SBtdv/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working like charm. Can you tell me about 'for' loop because I will get daysInMonth like integer from other function. Is there any other way of looping in KO except foreach? I don't want do create array for daysInMonth if it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: There is no built in `for` binding in KO. So you need to create your daysInMonth array. However in a recent question somebody tries to implement one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089752/knockout-for-binding

Comment: But there are some [range implementation](http://underscorejs.org/#range) which can help you to create your days array.